# Can i set session id by my own?

Tags: codeigniter

Can I set a session id manually? I am using CodeIgniter with one Jquery plugin (uploadify) that loses the session id. I can send it in a post request, but can I set it explicitly on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be clearer - with code examples of what you need.

You can of course use your own Session variables these points should get you started.

CI Session Class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

PHP Sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: I think you need to be clear on my question. I am using Jquery uploadify and it is well known for not preserving the session. You can surf the net and find dozens of articles. My question is the same. I've read other post but didn't find answer so i am posting again :- Can i set session id on server side explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your session information from outside of CI and POST it.

There's a thread on the CI forums that attempts to solve this. You could probably [look into it](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/138823/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a problem where if you use the Uploadify plugin a couple of times your session expires? If so, simply append a unique timestamp to the ajax call that uploadify makes, and that should solve the problem of sessions expiring.

Comment: - I have no idea what you are talking about. But my problem is each time i use Uploadify plugin a new session id gets generated on the server.